# Add some div inside leaflet tag HTML

Tags: html, jquery, css, leaflet, maps

This is an overview of my leaflet map.
[image]

and what I need is like this :
[image]

there's a new div inside map like that, but when I try  it like this
**HTML CODE**

```
<div id='myMap' class='lorem'>
    <div class='ipsum'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.lorem{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   z-index: 1;
}

.lorem .ipsum{
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: red:
}
```

but the result is the red div is still inside the map
I can see the red div when the map (leaflet) is refreshing the map
[image]

I know if I do like this is work, but that's not what I want

```
<div id='myMap' class='lorem'></div>
<div class='ipsum'></div> // with height is 100vh
```

Comment: Why you dont want to have the div outside, this is the only easy solution. Else take a look into https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Comment: Thank you for the information about sidebar-2, I just want to know why the red div is still behind the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve.

If you would like to have the red div next to the map, you should probably not embed it in your map div.

If you want the div to be part of the map, you should set an absolute position to it, and then play with the z-index.

For example,

```
.ipsum {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

With a z-index of 1000, you will be above the map tiles, but under the control zoom. Try higher and your div will be above every leaflet element.

See https://jsfiddle.net/ft5c4euq/2/